# AT32F413RCT7 detected as Cortex-M0

Tags: cortex-m, cpuid

The chip in the photo appears to be https://www.arterychip.com/en/product/AT32F413.jsp but the name "DJ" does not match "Artery" and the chip is identified as Cortex-M0, i.e. the value read from address 0xE000ED00 "CPUID" is 0x410CC200, what is wrong with this chip?

[image: AT32F413RCT7]

I've tried using OpenOCD, Keil, ST Programmer and others, and I always get the same result, according to the name "AT32F413" I was waiting to find a Cortex-M4.

Comment: The manufacturer that you have linked to is making fake STM32 parts (eg: this is supposed to be a fake STM32F413).  I presume that this is why you expect it to be an M4 core.  You cannot trust anything in their documentation or labelling says, this is the whole point, you are buying fakes.  If you want something that matches the STM32 documentation, buy from ST.  Unless you are making very large volumes, the price shouldn't matter.  Only if you are making very large volumes then it may become worth your while to learn how these parts differ from the real thing.